# Getting media (images and videos) saved in document directory and display in collection view cell

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have picked the images and video from phpicker and saved them in same folder in documents directory. Now i want to show them in same collection view ..

I tried getting the urls using contentsOfDirectoryAtPath and it returned an array of urls of all the photos and videos. What should be the next step ?

How to know the media type of each url in array that if that url is of image or video?  and then how to set imageview if url is of image and set uiview with av video if url is of video.?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.